# Degree Symbol in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, symbols

I have tried just using "°" for degree symbols but as it shows on the image, it does not work as I wanted
`println(s"$avgTemp °C")`
[Method1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1SbD.png)

I have also tried "\u00B0" for degree symbols but it also showed the same as "°".
`println(s"$avgTemp \u00B0 C")`
[Method2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR6I3.png)

I have searched and could not find a solution.
I'm using scala version 1.12.11
and I used sbt to run scala

Comment: It works for me, it is probably a problem with either your terminal or with your keyboard configuration.

Comment: I used cmd to run my program and my keyboard config is English (United States) US Keyboard

Comment: It does not look like a Scala problem but has to do with your terminal and locale settings.

Comment: If you use an English Windows system, your code page inside the terminal is probably set to [OEM 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), but the default encoding used by the JVM is [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). You can change the code page with `chcp`, e.g. `chcp 65001`. Then, start your JVM with `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`. Does this work?

Comment: Understood, thanks everyone!